# where is the place to auto install maven in jenkins 2.0

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-plugin

In previous version of Jenkins it was possible to install maven with auto installer. but from Jenkins 2.0 it seems to that feature is not provided. where is the place to auto install maven in Jenkins 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see maven auto installation inside **Manage Jenkins | Global Tool Configuration**

Also you may need to install the [maven plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin) separately for building Maven project

Comment: Thank you soo much. I wasted loads of time by searching this. It worked. :D

Comment: As of Jenkins 2.83.3, there is no such thing as Global Tool Configuration in Settings.

Comment: in which folder it put maven (automatic installer)?